# 2013 MBP unable to see new internal SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, high-sierra

So I have a 2013 MBP that I'm trying to install to give to my friend. I've bee running a 500GB Samsung Evo 850 for a few years. I'm trying to put in a 250GB one in.

I've managed to install macOS High Sierra when in a usb cage I've got. It boots just fine off of my original SSD. So I don't think it's the cable or the ssd.

I've been installing off of a USB installer I made using my new macbook. I've reset the SMC and PRAM.

EDIT:

No idea what's going on. I've given up and left the 500GB drive in the computer while I keep the 250GB with my stuff on it on the side.

Comment: Does disk utility see it?

Comment: No. Not even showing all devices.

Answer (score 2):

Is the new SSD properly formatted?
I’ve had issues before where the drive was still FAT or whatever, but the Mac partition was properly formatted and looked ok.

Comment: So it doesn't show even when I click show all drives. My old ssd does and is fine. So when I boot off of the USB, go into Disk Utility, I can't even format it there. I had to format it from another computer.

It also boots off of it. I got to the OS setup screen when attached via USB, so it's installed the os. Was also formatted to MacOS Journaled with a GUID partition.